# ordering a text field which has range of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field called customer-range which has values in the following way for some customers:

```
Customer ID, Customer-range
1111,[0-1]
1111,[1-2]
1111,[2-3]
```

And for some customers it would be just an integer like this:

```
2222, 11
2222, 3
2222, 14
```

So basically I want to write a select statement ordering the customer range. It's a text field in the database. How can I achieve this?

This is what I tried, with the help of Google and an online friend:

```
;WITH MyCTE
AS (
    SELECT 1111 CustID
        ,'[0-1]' CustomerRange

    UNION

    SELECT 1111
        ,'[10-13]'

    UNION

    SELECT 1111
        ,'[7-10]'


    )
SELECT *
    ,CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('[', CustomerRange) = 0
            THEN '[' + CustomerRange + '-' + CustomerRange + ']'
        ELSE CustomerRange
        END SortedBy
FROM MyCTE
ORDER BY CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('[', CustomerRange) = 0
            THEN '[' + CustomerRange + '-' + CustomerRange + ']'
        ELSE CustomerRange
        END
```

Above code works when the integer values are less than 10, but don't seem to order them for any value more than 9.
The order  from above example should be
      [0-1]
      [7-10]
      [10-13]

Thank You

Comment: Could you please provide us a sample result that you are expecting? It would definitely help.

Comment: What you are experiencing is sorting strings and expecting them to sort like numbers. Strings sort by ascii value of each character where numbers sort by the entire value because what we see is the string interpretation of that number. In other words it is sorting exactly as you told it to, by the ascii value of each position within the string. Unfortunately that isn't how you want it sorted. The real question is how do you want it sorted?

Comment: I have edited my question in order to make things more clear. Sorry for posting the question in haste.Will be more neater next time.

Comment: you should avoid storing composite values as text in fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data structure does not follow good normalization practices. You should have CustomerRange in two columns. One low and one high number. Since you probably can't change it though, here's a query that will do what I think you want, which is sorting by CustID and the first number in CustomerRange.

```
WITH MyCTE
AS
(
    SELECT 1111 CustID,CustomerRange
    FROM (VALUES('0-1'),('10-13'),('7-10')) AS A(CustomerRange)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 2222,CustomerRange
    FROM (VALUES('11'),('3'),('14')) B(CustomerRange)
)

SELECT  CustID,
        CustomerRange,
        CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX('-',CustomerRange) = 0
                THEN CONCAT('[',CustomerRange,'-',CustomerRange,']')
            ELSE CONCAT('[',CustomerRange,']')
        END Range_With_Brackets,
        order_col
FROM MyCTE
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(LEFT(CustomerRange,CHARINDEX('-',CustomerRange + '-' ) - 1) AS INT)) CA(order_col)
ORDER BY CustID,order_col
```

Results:

```
CustID      CustomerRange Range_With_Brackets order_col
----------- ------------- ------------------- -----------
1111        0-1           [0-1]               0
1111        7-10          [7-10]              7
1111        10-13         [10-13]             10
2222        3             [3-3]               3
2222        11            [11-11]             11
2222        14            [14-14]             14
```

Comment: Thank You works like a charm. Stephan where can i pass the where condition in this query in orderder to pass the CustID paramater for filtering data.

Comment: Hi Stephan, Sorry but the value for ranges dont have the [] braces. They are just 0-1,1-3,11-13. Can you modify the code for these values.  Thank you

Comment: Yes no problem. I changed it and I don't really know how you want the results formatted so I just threw Range_With_Brackets in just as an example. Hope this one works properly

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
;WITH MyCTE
AS (
    SELECT 1111 CustID
        ,'[0-1]' CustomerRange

    UNION

    SELECT 1111
        ,'[10-13]'

    UNION

    SELECT 1111
        ,'[7-10]'
    )
    ,MyCTE1
AS (
    SELECT CustID
        ,CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('[', CustomerRange) = 0
                THEN '[' + CustomerRange + '-' + CustomerRange + ']'
            ELSE CustomerRange
            END SortedBy
    FROM MyCTE
    )
    ,MySortCTE
AS (
    SELECT replace(substring(sortedby, charindex('-', sortedby) + 1, len(sortedby)), ']', '') AS sort_num
        ,CustID
        ,SortedBy
    FROM MyCTE1
    )
SELECT CustID,SortedBy
FROM mySortCTE
--  WHERE CUSTID = 1111   uncomment this line to filter CustID
ORDER BY sort_num
```

Comment: Thanks Stephan..that was awesome.

Comment: Did this help you at all?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really understand the way you expect it to order but in response to your comment "when the integer values are less than 10, but don't seem to order them for any value more than 9", it looks like it is treating your numbers as strings and that is why not ordering correctly. e.g. numeric 11 is greater than 9 but string "11" is less than "9"

You'll have to use CAST to convert your strings to numeric